# Is it possible to create a generic 'Class' variable in an abstract class and then use the variable as a generic to validate its own data?

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

Maybe I got the wrong idea, but I'm doing some extensive parsing and I wanted to add some safety related to the information that runs around, my idea was to make an abstract class that would force some things. This is what I got so far:

```
package data.abstracts;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

public abstract class DataStructure {

    @Getter
    private static String name;
    @Setter
    private Class dataStructure;

    public abstract boolean validateDataStructure(dataStructure ds);
    public abstract void setData();
}
```

The idea is that dataStructure be a POJO class and that the ValidateDataStructre method be implemented depending on the class used in the dataStructre.

Is there any way of doing this? Because I could eventually use reflection to write the method to validate the structure.

EDIT:

AxelH stated the obvious, I can use this. to access any internal information from the class (duh), I should change dataStructure to Object and I think my problems are solved!

Comment: You probably wanted the type of the `dataStructure` field to be `Object` instead of `Class`? Or even better use a generic type parameter.

Comment: Every non-abstract sub class of `DataStructure` would need to implement `ValidateDataStructure`, so yes. (if I get your question), if you want to validate the pojo itself, you don't need a parameter, `this` will be the instance. But I am not sure this is what you want. Please see [ask]. FYI: watch you naming convention...

Comment: The naming is all over the place, `ValidateDataStructure` should start with a lowercase `v`, the parameter should be of type `DataStructure` with a capital `D`, etc.

Comment: Could you use generic arguments? like `public abstract class DataStructure<T extends DataStructure<T>>` and then `private Class<T> dataStructure`?